# how to check condition while creating view in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, view, null

I am creating a view with joining 2 tables.
I have a column license in which I have grouped it to a single cell with a separator. The license field may have null values for the corresponding service in the referring tables.  so while viewing the license column for a particular agent it should show null values along with the separator.

For example , agent `id = 802` , His service column is grouped with many services with a separator which looks like

```
Mututal Funds||Investments||Life Insurance||Personal Loan
123456       ||NULL       ||34567         ||NUL
```

where license value for Investments and persoanl loan is NULL but what i get is **123456||34567**  the null values are rejected automatically ... but i need Null to be included in resultset .... My Query is

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `v_agent_service` AS 
select `a`.`agent_id` AS `agent_id`,
       group_concat(`a`.`license`separator '||') AS `license`,
       group_concat(`s`.`service_name` separator '||') AS  `service_names` 
from 
(`agent_service` `a` left join `service` `s` 
on((`s`.`service_id`  = `a`.`service_id`)))
group by `a`.`agent_id`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `IFNULL()` to turn a null value into a string containing `'null'`:

```
group_concat(IFNULL(`a`.`license`, 'NULL') separator '||') AS `license`,
```

Comment: thanks ... but the beauty is i already found this answer before c ing ur answer ... but pls continue ur support for my future questions too ...